# Typescript. Define type for object of functions

Tags: typescript

Sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-meninsky-nuvjh?file=/src/index.ts)

I have an object with different functions

```
const objectOfFunctions = {
  getFromNumber: (arg: number) => arg,
  getFromString: (arg: string) => arg,
  getFromBoolean: (arg: boolean) => arg
};
```

I need to define types for data

```
const data: DataTypes = [
  {
    type: 'getFromNumber',
    arg: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'getFromNumber',
    arg: 10
  },
  {
    type: 'getFromString',
    arg: 'qwerty'
  },
  {
    type: 'getFromBoolean',
    arg: true
  }
];
```

My types are:

```
type TypeOfObject = typeof objectOfFunctions;
type ObjectKeys = keyof TypeOfObject;
interface ObjectType<T extends ObjectKeys> {
  type: T
  arg: Parameters<TypeOfObject[T]>[0];
}

type DataTypes = (
  ObjectType<'getFromNumber'> |
  ObjectType<'getFromString'> |
  ObjectType<'getFromBoolean'>
)[]
```

To execute the desired function for each element of the array.

```
data.forEach((dataItem) => {
  const func = objectOfFunctions[dataItem.type];
  const {arg} = dataItem;
  func(arg)
})
```

And typesctipt throws error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    const func = objectOfFunctions[dataItem.type];
    const {arg} = dataItem;
  > func(arg)
         ^^^
    })
```

How do I correctly define types for DataTypes?

Thanks in advance :)